# ICS file dynamic timezone issue

Tags: php, timezone, icalendar, timezone-offset

I am trying to generate ics file dynamically in PHP, where timezone is dynamic according to the location given. Everything works good but there is daylight time issue i.e it shows time difference of one hour or so. Now to solve this issue I have to use `DAYLIGHT` dynamically. but I don't know how to use it dynamically, or where from can I get `TZOFFSETFROM` and `TZOFFSETTO` offsets related with timezone given.

For Example:

```
    $timeZone = "America/Denver" // dynamically fetched from DB

      $ical = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n";
      $ical .= "VERSION:2.0\n";
      $ical .= "PRODID:-//LokalMotion//LokalMotion Events v1.0//EN\n";
      $ical .= "CALSCALE:GREGORIAN\n";
      $ical .= "METHOD:PUBLISH\n";
      $ical .= "X-WR-CALNAME:LokalMotion Events\n";
      $ical .= "X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE\n";
      $ical .= "BEGIN:VTIMEZONE\n";
      $ical .= "TZID:{$timeZone}\n";
      $ical .= "TZURL:http://tzurl.org/zoneinfo-outlook/{$timeZone}\n";
      $ical .= "X-LIC-LOCATION:{$timeZone}\n";
      $ical .= "END:VTIMEZONE\n";
      $ical .= "BEGIN:VEVENT\n";
      $ical .= "DTSTAMP:".date('Ymd\THis\Z')."\n";
      $ical .= "DTSTART;TZID={$timeZone}:{$start_date}\n";
      $ical .= "DTEND;TZID={$timeZone}:{$end_date}\n";
      $ical .= "STATUS:CONFIRMED\n";
      $ical .= "SUMMARY:{$title}\n";
      $ical .= "DESCRIPTION:{$description}\n";
      $ical .= "ORGANIZER;CN=Reminder:MAILTO:support@mysite.com\n";
      $ical .= "CLASS:PUBLIC\n";
      $ical .= "CREATED:{$start_date}Z\n";
      $ical .= "LOCATION:{$location}\n";
      $ical .= "URL:http://www.mysite.com\n";
      $ical .= "SEQUENCE:1\n";
      $ical .= "LAST-MODIFIED:".date('Ymd\THis\Z')."\n";
      $ical .= "UID:{$title}-support@mysite.com\n";
      $ical .= "END:VEVENT\n";
      $ical .= "END:VCALENDAR";    

echo $ical;
```

Now how to use daylight dynamically according to the location, like location can be 'America/Caracas' .. etc

```
$ical .= "BEGIN:DAYLIGHT";
$ical .= "TZOFFSETFROM:{}"; //I need this dynamic
$ical .= "TZOFFSETTO:{}";//I need this dynamic
$ical .= "TZNAME:EDT";
$ical .= "DTSTART;TZID={$timeZone}:{$start_date}\n";
$ical .= "RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU";
$ical .= "END:DAYLIGHT";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may be able to use the information from `DateTimeZone::getTransitions` to fill the values properly.  See [these docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.gettransitions.php).

Comment: Thanks Matt for your support.

Comment: Do not use "Z" at the end of your datetime stamp because in this case Outlook and iCal will use this time as UTC and recalculate it according to your local timezone.

Comment: @Art: Unfortunately Google Calendar does not appear to support "floating" time formats (ie. without the "Z" at the end), it defaults to UTC in such cases!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Before converting times and date, you should set the correct timezone in PHP so the engine knows the time characteristics of the zone you are using:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
$start_date = date('c', time());   // ISO date 8601 of "right now"
$start_zone = date('O', time());   // TZOFFSETFROM format  of "right now"

date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');
$to_zone = date('O', time());   // TZOFFSETTO of "right now"
```

Hope this may help

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer?  It does not address how to fill the `TZOFFSETFROM` and `TZOFFSETTO` values dynamically, which was the heart of the original question

Comment: I think it was working fine, as I used `$start_zone = date('O', time());   // TZOFFSETFROM` and then I set  `date_default_timezone_set($timeZone);` and further I set `$end_zone = date('O', time());` for TZOFFSETTO

Comment: That's not what `TZOFFSETFROM` and `TZOFFSETTO` are supposed to represent.  See [these docs](http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/vtimezone.html).  You also need to fill the `DTSTART` value.

Comment: Matt, I guess that is just an example on how to build the timezone with the right format. Bheem will know where to catch from the "from" and "to" timezones from his application. Efectively, the TO does not refer the end time, but the destination timezone of the DTSTART, i correct the proposal

Comment: The ical spec says that the TZOFFSETFROM value is the offset of the previous transition - not of right now.